# Omit the last line with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm having the following file content.

```
2013-07-30 debug
line1
2013-07-30 info
line2
line3
2013-07-30 debug
line4
line5
```

I want to get the following output with `sed`.

```
2013-07-30 info
line2
line3
```

This command gives me nearly the output I want

```bash
sed -n '/info/I,/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/{p}' myfile.txt
```

```
2013-07-30 info
line2
line3
2013-07-30 debug
```

How do I omit the last line here?

Comment: How about `awk`? `awk '/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/{level = $2} level == "debug"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -n '/info/I p; //,/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/{ //! p}' myfile.txt
```

It prints first match, and in range omits both edges but the first one is already printed, so only skips the second one. It yields:

```
2013-07-30 info
line2
line3
```

Answer (score 4):

IMO, sed starts to become unwieldy as soon as you have to add conditions into it. I realize you did not tag the question with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), but here is an awk program to print only "info" sections.

```
awk -v type="info" '
    $1 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/ {p = ($2 == type)} 
    p
' myfile.txt
```

```
2013-07-30 info
line2
line3
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/info/I{:a;n;/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/!ba;s/^/\n/;D};d' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed '/info/I{:a;n;/^....-..-.. /!ba;s/^/\n/;D};d' file
```

N.B. This caters for consecutive patterns